# How to insert a global variable into a local variable?

Tags: python

I'm a beginner, can someone explain why I can't import a into a function?

```
import random   
a = random.randint(1,99)

def frog():  
    frog = a  
(frog)
```

Comment: do you intent to print??.... print(frog)??

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? I really don't have a clue. You have a function frog, and a variable frog?

Comment: What are you expecting `(frog)` to do?

Comment: please explain better what you want to do. are you trying to return the "a" when you call the function?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow. Just to let you know, there is a button when asking a question in the toolbar that looks like `{}` to let you format code blocks. Since white-space is significant in Python, it's particularly important to use it so we can see the indents. That said, the question isn't very clear. Can you rephrase it to better explain what you want to do?

Comment: The definition of the function `frog` is fine; it assigns the value of the global `a` to a local variable also named `frog` (which, aside from preventing you from making a recursive call to `frog`, is perfectly OK). The last line of your example doesn't make any sense, though. It's just a parenthesized reference to your function; it doesn't *call* the function. That would be `frog()`, but you wouldn't observe any effect from calling it as currently defined.

Comment: What are you asking for exactly? This code `def frog():  
    frog = a  
(frog)` is just not Python, and you failed to describe what you were trying to achieve. Please read [ask].

Comment: @SergeBallesta What do you mean with "is just not Python"?

Comment: @StefanPochmann: I meant that the syntax while correct does not probably lead to what OP expects. Using the name of a function to set the return value is Fortran not Python...

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated, it's hard to know what you're trying to accomplish. Are you trying to print the result of the frog() method? To do that, you need to `return` something (or print the result from inside the method).

```
import random   
a = random.randint(1,99)

def frog():  
    a_frog = a
    return a_frog

print(frog())
```

Also, to make things less confusing, it's best not to use a variable name that is the same as the method name.

UPDATE:
In rereading your question, you ask why you can't import `a` into a function.  You're actually doing that just fine. This version shows that it's working:

```
import random   
a = random.randint(1,99)

def frog():  
    a_frog = a
    print(a_frog)

frog()
```